# Select and join with sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

How to make this code with the sequelize?

I used include, but it brings all the user data but I only need the name

```sql
select comments.comment, users.name from comments inner join users on comments.userId = users.id
```

my code:

```js
Comments.findAll({
       where: {
           projectId: id
       },
       include:  User
   }).then(response =>{
      
           res.json({comments: response})
       })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to reduce `User` model attributes then just indicate needed attributes in the `attributes` option:

```js
Comments.findAll({
       where: {
           projectId: id
       },
       include:  [{ 
         model: User,
         attributes: ['name']
       }]
   }).then(response =>{
      
           res.json({comments: response})
       })
```

If you want to add a user's name as a string prop at the same level as all `Comments` fields simply indicate it in the `attributes` option of `Comments` model with a desired alias:

```js
Comments.findAll({
       where: {
           projectId: id
       },
       attributes: [[Sequelize.col('Users.name'), 'userName']],
       include:  [{ 
         model: User,
         attributes: []
       }]
   }).then(response =>{
      
           res.json({comments: response})
       })
```